# Selecting all numbers from 0 to 6 except 1 JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to select all numbers from 0 to 6 except n (n<=6, n>=0).
I am quite sure it is simple js, but I didn't find an answer for it.

Please, if possible, provide a vanilla js answer.

For example: 
n = 3

I want to select all numbers from 0-6 without 3 aka 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6

Comment: for(i=0;i<n;i++) {if (i != n) {/*Do your stuff*/}}

Comment: This question needs a lot more context and maybe some code you've already tried using to solve the problem.

Comment: Store your numbers in an array and delete the one with value n

Comment: @DarthMoon is it possible to add to the for loop i<6? Btw, wouldn't it stop working if, for example, n=3? (won't check 4-6?)

Comment: @DarthMoon how do I do that? (deleting from array?)

Comment: what means *all numbers*?

Comment: @NinaScholz 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: @GuyAdler: That's all numbers from 0-6.  Where does "except n" come into play?  Can you perhaps provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could generate an array first with the numbers and then filter the values.

```js
var length = 7,
    except = 3,
    result = Array
        .from({ length }, (_, i) => i)
        .filter(n => n !== except);
        
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so and they all are fairly simple. Think a bit of it: you want to iterate through an interval of numbers while excluding number n from it. So you could:

Check every iteration if number n is reached or not

```
var n;  //Your bad number, isn't it?
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  //Check every time if n is reached
  if (i == n) {
    //Just do nothing, the bad number is reached
  }
  //But if not...
  else {
    //doYourStuff
  }
  //Here your script will jump back to the for loop with i += 1 also if n was reached
}
```

An other way would be to store every number in an array and delete the bad number after it

```
var n;  //Bad number
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; //You could do this more dynamically, just google it
numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(n), 1); //Removes the bad number
```

Hope it helps!
Darth Moon